# How do I check the exhaust system for damage after being rear ended at about 5mph?

Tags: exhaust, damage, inspection

After my [last question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26533/ive-just-been-rear-ended-have-i-done-any-damage), where I was rear-ended at about 5mph, I was told to check my exhaust system for damage. However I know nothing about to look out for.

**What should I look out for?**

**What common damage occurs to the exhaust after a shunt?**

My car is a 2003 Opel Agila

Comment: What's the definition of "shunt" in this context?

Comment: @JPhi1618, Somebody drove into the back of my car at about 5mph while I was stopped. Clarified the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go under the car with a flashlight and check the overall area where you have been rear ended. There is usually a absorbtion plate on the bumpers, so it is highly unlikely that your exhaust is damaged. Just check for dents in the exhaust and the absorbtion plate. Check for visual irregularities. You can shine the flashlight and get an idea of irregularities from the reflections. I highly doubt that there is any damage.

Answer (score 3):

At that speed, there really shouldn't be any damage.  Just be sure that:
There isn't anything bent in a way that would restrict flow
Hangers still hold the exhaust solidly in place (not hanging down or dragging)